# Pandas Count Using Multiple Rows

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe df that contains 3 columns: name, state, status. The data contains people with/without the same names, in different states, and their sleep status (awake, asleep).

- Column "name" contains various names..e.g., 'amy', 'brooke', 'tom', 'mike', 'sam'
- Column "State" contains various state names
- Column "status" contains "asleep" or "awake"

I want to first filter by name.. so when `df['name'][1]` output a count of the "awakes" and "asleep". There will be multiple awake and asleep entries as there will be multiple brookes in different states.

I'm confused on how I can go about using `df['name'][1]` to then count the number of awake and asleeps.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you provide us a sample dataset and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want value_counts which is a Series method.  We can do a groupby on name and and take the value_counts in the sleep column to get a count per group.  For example:

```
s ='''
    name state sleep
    bob s1 awake
    bob s2 asleep
    bob s3 awake
    rob s1 awake
    rob s2 asleep
    rob s3 awake
    rob s1 asleep
    cindy s2 asleep
    cindy s3 awake
    cindy s1 awake
    cindy s2 asleep
    cindy s1 asleep
    cindy s1 awake
    cindy s2 asleep
    cindy s3 awake
   '''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s+')
df = df.groupby('name')['sleep'].value_counts()

name   sleep 
bob    awake     2
       asleep    1
cindy  asleep    4
       awake     4
rob    asleep    2
       awake     2
```